# How do we import archived OLM files into Apple Mail?

Tags: email, apple-mail, email-client

I bought a mac book pro a couple of days ago. I had these old archived email files from outlook 2011 stored on my external hard drive. I need to open these files in apple mail. How can I import olm files in apple mail?

Comment: I would prefer a solution that is easy to perform as I am new to this mac world. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to outlook 2011 ? We will need to use this to convert to apple mail mbox config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic has been covered multiple times over the course of time on multiple forums. It seems like there is no direct way to import your OLM files into Apple Mail. However, there are multiple third-party apps that convert OLM file format into MBOX format that can be imported into Apple Mail via Import function.

Google can be your best help here where you can find the best application that does the job done. Unfortunately, these products are not free.

I am linking some forum posts that already covered this topic, choose wisely:

1. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4976674
2. https://macosx.com/threads/how-to-import-mailbox-from-outlook-2011-into-mac-mail-lion.322176/#post1527155

Comment: As i had only the archived files of outlook mac in .olm format, I had no options left. I had to convert the olm files into mbox files. for that I used OLM Converter Pro, whcih I found while reading through those forum threads. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article on Ms TechNet concerning this very task - Works well and isn't too difficult.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/olm-file-to-apple-mail-b5835cdb